# Tcp accept fails after first connection after 1 hour

Tags: c++, tcp, client-server

I have written C++ client server application and the server is crashing.
The scenario

1. Start server
2. 1 hour later (not before) Client connect

Then the Server which is waiting in accept returns -1 with errno "Too many open files".

Nothing else special is running on the machine which led me to believe that accept is opening many file descriptors while waiting.
Is that true?
How can I fix this so the client could connect anytime?

the relevant server code:

```
int sockClient;
while (true) {

    sockaddr_in* clientSockAddr = new sockaddr_in();
    socklen_t clientSockAddrLen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

    sockClient = accept(sockServer, (sockaddr *) clientSockAddr,
                        &clientSockAddrLen);

    if(sockClient == -1 ){
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << "TCP Server: accept connection error." << std::strerror(errno);
        throw runtime_error(s.str());
    }

    connection->communicate(sockClient, clientSockAddr, clientSockAddrLen);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file descriptor leak somewhere. Possibly you aren't closing accepted sockets when you've finished with them, or else it's on a file somewhere.

Comment: In the scenario I have only one connection... and if the leak is somewhere else how come I only get the error in the above accept? I will go back and review other areas in the code for leaks. thanks.

Comment: I found the problem, Indeed EJB was right. I had a loop else where that tried to connect to another server but since it was missing the connection did not succeed but the socket was not released. It is not clear to me why "accept" fails and not "socket"...